# in html how we can store a user editable content into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this my editable table,i want to store the editable content into a varibale.help me
now the script is used only for change the td as editable one,
 my main aim is store this editable data into a variable and contro another div using this variable 
is it possible store a user editing data using script?

```
$(function () {
    $("td.task1").dblclick(function () {

        var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
        $(this).addClass("cellEditingtask1")

        $(this).html("<input  type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
    })
```

```css
.editableTable {
    position:static;
      width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse;


} 
.editableTable td { 
     border: 1px solid;
    border-color: lightgray;
    overflow:hidden;
   height:17px;
  /*max-height:10px;*/

}



  .editableTable .cellEditingtask1 input[type=text]{ 
      width:100%; 
     border:none;
     /*font-size:9px;*/
      /*text-align: center;*/
     background-color:transparent;
    color: rgb(178,178,178);

  }
  .editableTable .cellEditingsub1 {
      padding: 0;

 }
  .editableTable .cellEditingsub1 input[type=text]{ 
      width:100%; 
     border:none;
     font-size:12px;
      text-align: center;
     background-color:transparent;
      color: rgb(102,102,102);

  }
    .editableTable .cellEditingsub1 {
      padding: 0;

 }
        .editableTable .cellEditingmain1 input[type=text] {

            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: transparent;
             color: rgb(0,0,0);
        }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="tableleft" class="editableTable">
      <tr>
        <td class="task1">23</td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function on focusout. Is this what you want?

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
    $("td.task1").dblclick(function () { 
        var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
        $(this).addClass("cellEditingtask1");

        $(this).html("<input id='editInput' type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
    });


    $("td.task1").focusout(function () { 

        var OriginalContent = $("td.task1 #editInput").val();
        $(this).removeClass("cellEditingtask1"); 
        $(this).html(OriginalContent);
        alert(OriginalContent);
    });

    });
</script>
```